# Is it possible to compile Lucene.net 2.9.4 for .Net 2.0?

Tags: .net-2.0, lucene.net

I'm trying to integrate Lucene.net into an old .Net 2.0 application. Scanning the mailing list, I've been given the impression that 2.9.4g no longer supports .Net 2.0 but 2.9.4 does. However, the compiled dll disallows the .Net 2.0 framework, and the source makes use of System.Core (which can be added, though I'd rather not if avoidable) and ThreadLocal.

Am I missing something? Does 2.9.4 not support .Net 2.0? If this is the case, what's the most recent version of Lucene.net to support .Net 2.0?

Edit:

2.9.4 and 2.9.4g are two separate versions. As I understand, 2.9.4g was heavily refactored to use newer .Net generics, making it completely incompatible with .Net 2.0. I'm interested in the 2.9.4 version, before the refactoring.

Here's the post that implies 2.9.4 will run under 2.0: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-dev/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=fLnbGa1+ns92n+L9XZoUO9ttb_w@mail.gmail.com%3E .

Edit 2:

If 2.9.4 can support .Net 2.0 with modification, could someone point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish that?

Comment: generics are not the issue, .Net2.0 supports them. It doesnt work because it uses new 4.0 classes like ThreadLocal

Answer (score 0):

If you don't modify it, 2.9.4g will not compile on .Net 2.0. It uses several new classes and you will need to use libraries/code alternatives yourself.

The last version I know of that works on .Net 2.0 is 2.9.2.2.

http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/2.9.2.2

I think there are plans to make the next version, 3.0.3 .Net 2.0 compatible, but I dont know for sure if it will be done. There are compilation symbols for .Net 2.0 in the project build files, but they are not used yet.

Comment: 2.9.4g doesn't support .Net 2.0, but I'm wondering about 2.9.4. (The g version was refactored to use .Net's generics, hence the "g.") This is the post that implies to me 2.9.4 will support .Net 2.0 with a little bit of tweaking: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-dev/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=fLnbGa1+ns92n+L9XZoUO9ttb_w@mail.gmail.com%3E .

Comment: The last release candidate of 2.9.4 does not support 2.0 out of the box, you can get it here http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_4_RC3/

Comment: Is there a way to modify it so it does support 2.0, though?

Comment: Yes, the class SupportClass in the root of the project from earlier versions is a good starting point

Comment: I was able to get 2.9.4 to run in .Net 2.0 simply by using the CloseableThread.cs file (prior to implementing ThreadLocal) from Lucene.net 2.9.2. I'm not a fan of the hack nature, but it doesn't seem to cause problems, and I'm short on time, so it'll have to work...